# I want to scroll down to Specific element using appium in Android, java client v-5.0.4 and appium v-1.7.1

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am trying to scroll down to an element, looked and searched everywhere and no code is helping to scroll down, i have tried with the code below which seems to be not working, anyone gives me the solution to scroll down perfectly.
As swipe and scrollTo functions are depreciated in the latest java client version, a perfect code will help me to solve my TASK

```
package mobileapp.com.example;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidFindBy;

public class Day5 {

    AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;

    @AndroidFindBy (uiAutomator = "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"PHP\"))")
    public WebElement scrollStepOne;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "6.0.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Nexus 5");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.vector.guru99");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.vector.guru99.BaseActivity");

    driver= new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    }

    @Test
    public void StartTest() throws InterruptedException {

        //Verify Homepage
        if(driver.findElement(By.id("android:id/action_bar_title")).isDisplayed())
            System.out.println("Home page is displayed");
        else
            System.out.println("Home page is not displayed");

        //step2 - click on Course List tab

        driver.findElement(By.name("Course List")).click();
        System.out.println("Courses list are : ");
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        //Step 3 - darg until PHP course found and click on it
        scrollStepOne.click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
//      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text()='PHP']")).click();
//      Thread.sleep(3333);

        //Step 4 - Click on lesson 1 and verify
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='What is PHP? Write your first PHP Program']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3333);

        if(driver.findElement(By.id("com.vector.guru99:id/lesson_title")).isDisplayed())
            System.out.println("First Lesson is displayed");
        else
            System.out.println("First lesson not opened");


    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you specify if it is native, hybrid or webapp?

Comment: i am using native app only

Answer (score 0):

for scrolling to a element have a text as App_Settings, you can use the below

```
 androidDriver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0))" +
        ".scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().description(\"App_Settings\"));");
```

Comment: Hi JC, i am using latest version of appium and java client, and in this version use of findElementByAndroidUIAutomator is depreciated. Kindly give another way for scrolling